# OpenLayers container position from lat/long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

Is it possible to get position inside the OpenLayers container from a lat/long point?

Google Maps has something like this:

var markerOffset = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(marker.getLatLng());

Can I do the same thing in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `getPixelFromLonLat`[1] method from map object.

1 - http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getPixelFromLonLat